# How to calculate if the difference from current date and another date is equal or minus of a number of days

Tags: php, mysql

I use this query to calculate if the current date minus another date is minus or equal an amount of days. Unfortunately this query only works if the calculation of days is inside the same month. Let's take for example these datas:

current_date is: 30/08/2019 and another day is: 27/08/2019 minus or equal 3, the query works but if the current date is, for example, 01/09/2019 it doesn't work as it returns an empty list.

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT * FROM condominio WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - condominio.revisione) <= 5
```

The date are store inside the column in this format: "yyyy-mm-dd" so I think it is correct. I need to put some other data togheter with current_date to have the right values returned from the query?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right code for my goal:

```
SELECT * FROM condominio WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(), DATE_ADD(revisione, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) <= 30;
```

Hope it can help someone else now or in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

This query may help you.

```
SELECT * FROM condominio AS a WHERE DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, a.revisione ) <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(CURRENT_DATE - condominio.revisione) <= 5
```

is equivalent to

```
CURRENT_DATE <= 5 + condominio.revisione
```

or

```
CURRENT_DATE - 5 <= condominio.revisione
```

and that can be expressed as

```
SELECT *
FROM condominio
WHERE condominio.revisione >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

If you have an index on `revisione`, this will also be faster than using `DATEDIFF()`, because an index can't be used, if the indexed column is wrapped into a function call.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('27/08/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y/%m/%d') ,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('30/08/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y/%m/%d') ) AS 'Date'
```

this function return the diff between the date.

good lock!

Comment: sorry for replying only now but I discovered a strange behaviour (at least for me) and so here i am to ask help one more time.. please let me know if I have to open a new post or if I can still use this one..

For some unknown reason (for me), this query doesn't work as it should if i have this situation..

this is the query: 

$query = "SELECT * FROM condominio AS a WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, a.revisione ) <= " . $giorni . "";

these are the values:  CURRENT_DATE = today's date, a.revisione = 01/01/2019 and $ giorni = 100 . it returns as date difference 255.. why?

Comment: hi,if i run this query select DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(),'01/01/2019' ) <=100

Comment: he return me -257. Because from today's date to 01/01/2019, 257 days have passed.good lock!

Comment: look in this totrial:http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-datediff-function/

Comment: I tried different queries and functions but none worked.. It only works if the two dates belong to the same year but if one date is for example: 2018-10-30 and other date is CURRENT_DATE() it doesn't work.. moreover, the datediff() function accept only two parameters and not three.. I don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: it's work ! The third parameter determines what will return the difference between the dates: day, month, or year
It works great !!!

Comment: I really sorry but this function requires three parameters !!!
Take a look at all the help materials ...
For example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp
Anyway for me it works great with three parameters !!!!
That seems to me the best proof !!!

Comment: I am using MySQL and not SQL server and it accepts only 2 parameters..

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were working with MySQL. The examples I have offered are for SQL server. good luck!

Comment: f I have an idea how to solve your problem I'll share it with you, I've worked with before MySQL

Comment: I have found a solution today. Tomorrow when i come back to my office i will share the right syntax to achieve my goal

Comment: This is the right code for my goal:

SELECT * FROM condominio WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(), DATE_ADD(revisione, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) <= 30

Hope it can help someone else now or in the future :-)